# Generate an access token in the browser that is scoped to Kusto Azure Data Explorer

Tags: reactjs, azure, active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

From the command line I can generate an access token using:

`az account get-access-token`

However this access token won't work with `kusto` because the token has not been scoped.

`az account get-access-token --resource https://{name}.{location}.kusto.windows.net`

This provides an access token that is accepted by `kusto`.

My question relates to the `@azure/msal-browser` library and how I can scope the access token a specific `resource`. In the example below I am using `@azure/msal-react` which is just an abstraction layer on top of the underlying `@azure/msal-browser` library.

```js
import { useMsal, useAccount } from '@azure/msal-react';

const ControllerRequester = () => {
  const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();
  const account = useAccount(accounts[0] || {});

  if (Object.keys(accounts).length) {
    instance.acquireSilentToken({
      account,
      // What other properties do I need to include to scope the access token to kusto
    }).then(accessToken => doSomething(accessToken))
  }

  return <div>...</div>

}
```

I've tried a few different options, such as `scopes: ['https://{name}.{location}.kusto.windows.net/.default']` but without much success. I've also read other answers relating to the `msal` library but they haven't helped. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried acquiring token using `https://{name}{location}.kusto.windows.net`?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like currently this is used https://{name}.{location}.kusto.windows.net/.default

Try removing the .default

Answer (score 0):

correct, remove .default and try it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).